# Regex for capturing currency exchange rate

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python regex to extract the currency exchange rate from some chat messages. The messages have several different format, for example:

"... CAD/USD 0.xxx ..." (CAD to USD)

"... CADUSD 0.xxx ..." (CAD to USD)

"... EUR 1.xxx ..." (EUR to USD)

The currency could be in USD, EUR, CAD, CHY, SGD, etc.

I've tried to use the pattern :

```
r"(.*)\s+(USD|CAD|EUR|CHY|JPY)/?(USD|CAD|EUR|CHY|JPY)?\s+([0-9.]+)\s+(.*)"
```

but I always got the second currency, eg got only USD from CADUSD.

Could someone please tell me what is the right pattern I should use?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to capture, just the first currency? just the number? with your current regex you will get both currencies, the amount and the parts of the line before and after the currency part

Comment: Why not using `[A-Z]{3}` for the currency code? It's nearly impossible (and unnecessary) to list _all_ valid currency codes...

Comment: @Nullman I'm trying to capture the 2 currencies and the rate. If there is only 1 currency, the second one will have default value, e.g USD. The problem is with that regex, I can only capture the second currency.

Comment: @trolley813 I don't have to get all the currency, only some of them which I use in the pattern.

Comment: @vodka yes, but you can easily forget to include one of them, and potentially change the regex in _several_ places if you want to extend your list of currencies at some time. Of course, it doesn't matter for a _one-time_ script which is not needed to run repeatedly.

Comment: your regex works fine with the provided examples, could you provide an example that doesnt work for you?

Comment: @Nullman It doesn't but I fixed it. The regex should be `r"(.*?)...."` to capture the first currency.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below expression, first remove the unneeded stuff, then replace the `\s+` at the end with `\w+`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(SD|CAD|EUR|CHY|JPY).*(USD|CAD|EUR|CHY|JPY)\s+\d+.\w+", s)
[('CAD', 'USD')]
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation to accompany the supposed answer? What's your pattern doing that theirs isn't? Where did they go wrong?

Comment: @Will Added some